# Density of states of Fermi gas derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, quantum-statistics, density-of-states

I'm going over [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030024288). While deriving the gensity of states for a gas of fermions the author makes the following argument:

> Remember that we are treating the
> gas as having a set of states that can be occupied by various numbers of its
> particles. Those states are just the cells of the everyday position–momentum
> space that the gas can occupy: three spatial dimensions and three momentum
> dimensions. Counting those states then equates to counting the number of
> states available to one free particle moving in three spatial dimensions, given
> the constraint of some total energy $E$.

And then he differentiates the formula for number of states of 1 particle in 3d to obtain the density (and multiplies the density by $2s+1$ to account for spin).

I do not understand this. We have a gas of, let's say, $N$ fermions. Each of these particles has some particular coordinate in it's 6-D (or rather 7-D because 3-D position + 3-D momentum + 1D for spin). Then any combination of coordinates of each particle in their position-momentum space gives a valid state for the whole fermion gas. I don't see where the analogy with a single particle in 3D comes from.

Comment: You might find this useful: [Why is the density of states required conceptually? Should it be seen as a mathematical trick related to Fourier series?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/633907/247642)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that we are **not** actually finding **the gensity of microstates of a gas of fermions**! We are simply counting the denisty of available microstates for a single fermion in its position-momentum (or, more precisely, position-momentum-spin) space.

*As to why not the microstates of a gas as a whole.* It is because we use this density of single-fermion states together with *occupation number* which gives the average number of particles occupying the same cell **in position-momentum space available to one fermion**.